# Jquery .toggle() needs about 2 seconds

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have problems on my phone when toggling the slidebar with the menu button.
The button calls the `.toggle()` function of jQuery. 
You can see it there: www.kwk.artfulsolutions.de (resize window to the mobile version).

It's only happening one exactly 1 device of me: Oneplus One. and only in chrome. All other smartphones don't have problems. And it happens on every Oneplus One (asked other people).

So I looked at the timeline of Google Chromes dev tools. this is what happens:

[image]

as you can see it takes over 2 seconds. and this is quite annoying.

even when I'm toggling the menu items in the side bar. so everytime the `display` attribute changes...

how to fix this?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wrmz99be/

Comment: can you put your code into a js fiddle?

Comment: This isn't related to the problem, but it's a problem: in that "resize" handler, you check to see if the width is less than 1009 pixels and if it is you *reassign* a "click" handler without first removing any existing "click" handler. That means you could, over time, end up with many copies of the same "click" handler on that element, and all of them will be run on each "click".

Comment: @Pointy tried it. It removes all delays but the first click is still very laggy.